# Unable to load ListView from Parse

Tags: java, android, listview, parse-platform

I am trying to load a class namely `Country` from `Parse` which has one column called `Name` . However when I try to get the elements in `ListView`, I dont see anything in screen, I don't know where I am doing wrong.

Here is the Java Code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Parse.initialize(this, "app-id", "client-key");

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_big_board);

    types = new ArrayList<String>();

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Country");
    query.addAscendingOrder("Name");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> parseObjects, ParseException e) {
            if(e==null)
            {
                for(ParseObject type : parseObjects)
                {
                    String cnn = type.getString("Name");
                    types.add(cnn);
                }

            }
        }
    });

   ListView usersListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.usersListView);

    ArrayAdapter<String> namesArrayAdapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                    R.layout.user_list_item, types);
    usersListView.setAdapter(namesArrayAdapter);


}
```

And the XML for the Activity is :

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.sinch.messagingtutorial.app.ListUsersActivity"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="16dp"
        tools:context="com.example.messagingtutorial.app.ListUsersActivity"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:id="@+id/usersListView">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Also, the code for `user_list_item.xml` is :

```
    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/userListItem"
    android:textColor="#a9a9a9"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
```

And here is the snapshot of the Parse web console, in case! 
[image: Parse screenshot]

As a Beginner to Parse, I don't know if I am missing something, kindly let me know . Thanks!

Comment: You may want to add an else statement to the FindCallback to check for an exception.